# How old is King Magnífico?

Tags: wish-2023

In *Wish*, the sorcerous King Magnifico looks anywhere between his early forties (like his voice actor) up to perhaps a very youthful-looking sixty-something.

On the other hand, he *is* a powerful sorcerer, so he may have some method of slowing his aging, he did found the entire kingdom, and some of the lines about Asha's grandfather, Sabino, suggest that he has gone all 100 years of his life without having his wish granted, which would suggest that Magnifico could be quite a bit older.

So, how old is King Magnifico?

Comment: Sabino likely gave up his wish when he emigrated to the Kingdom as an adult.

Comment: @Valorum - Possibly, but the dialogue seemed to me to suggest that he had possibly been going to the wish ceremonies his whole life.